What does "Knew that soon you'd want to leave the nest" mean?
I am watching Disney movie, Tangled.
I would like to know the meaning of the phrase "Knew that soon you’d want to leave the nest" in Tangled.
I understand "that soon" means "very soon"
What I am curious is that the sentence doesn't have conjunction between "knew that soon" and "you'd want to leave the nest"
I guess "that" can be put between those phrases like "knew that soon (that) you'd want to leave the nest".
Please tell me if my understanding is correct.

Generally, beware of using lyrics from songs as examples of English prose. Songs mix up words and change the "natural" rhythm, order, and choice of words to fit the song. So they are often not examples of natural English.

You have not parsed the sentence correctly.
The express is "I know that ...."  the word "that" doesn't mean very.  It is a marker of a subordinate clause.   The subordinate clause states the fact that the person knows.
eg  "I know that {tomatoes are fruit}."
So the fact is "Soon, you would want to leave the nest" is the fact, and the speaker is saying, "I knew {this fact}".
The subject "I" has been omitted for lyrical reasons, not because it is correct grammar.
